# I am getting Uncaught Error. 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\\ufffd' in position 7: ordinal not in range(256) in python3

Tags: python, mysql

I have following set up for connecting MySQL database 8.0.

```
class ProductionAWSConfig:
    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@{host}/{db}?charset=utf8mb4'.format(**{
        'user': os.getenv('DB_USER', 'ADMIN'),
        'password': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD', 'PASS'),
        'host': os.getenv('DB_HOST', '10.0.0.x'),
        'db': os.getenv('DB_NAME', 'mydb'),
    })
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = False

Config = ProductionAWSConfig
```

However, when I fetch data from MySQL database, I get encording error.
Database encording is as followings.

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb3                        |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb3                        |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                         |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb3                        |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3                        |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

So, I shold be able to connect and fetch data.
But, I can not do it because of encording error.

Dose anyone has suggestion for this?

Answer (score 0):

When the password contains string like "=" and/or "=", PyMySql gives me encoding error.
So, I updated the password to something that dose not contain "=".